# Selenium for Parasoft SOATest jython script

Tags: selenium-webdriver

From past few days I'm trying to write some browser automation script with jython in Parasoft SOATest with no luck.

I tried webking api, with that I was able to open the browser and navigate to links but couldn't find any further documentation to continue. Then I tried to import Selenium as well from Jython extension tool (from selenium import WebDriver) but turns out Selenium package not found. As far as I know selenium comes with Parasoft SOATest by default. I can see some Selenium jar files there, but I'm not able to import them.

Can anyone guide me to a proper documentation of webking api for Parasoft or usage of Selenium through Jython within Parasoft?

Answer (score 1):

I see no answers and few views, so I will try to help. I use Python (not Jython) and never heard of Parasoft, so it will be just a more generic guidance. :-)

I assume importing selenium would be like importing any other Jython modules. So if you are not experienced Jython hacker, ask your local Jython guru, or ask on Jython forums (or on Stack Overflow here).

Another option might be to switch to standard Python? Much more help resources available.

As you can see, here you might not reach the audience with Parasoft skills. If you insist on Parasoft, try Parasoft-specific forums.

As always, Google is your friend. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for helping out. The problem is I need to work with Jython and Parasoft only, As the clients are using this tool. And its a VM I'm connecting to. So basically I don't have any admin rights to install Python or tinker with other libraries. But parasoft provides some browser automation tool inbuilt, which are not having any kind of documentation. Last time parasoft firum was updated on 2011, so that didn't help either. So looking for some documentation on those if someone already worked on parasoft soatest tool. Btw thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to see if clients can setup